# Setting up local static IP with netplan causes network to sleep

Tags: networking, raspberrypi, netplan, static-ip, cloud-init

I am currently setting up some rpi4 with ubuntu server 20.04,

I have setup their static IPs using netplan(Wired LAN) and
**Somehow they end up sleeping in both SSH and TCP, if left for more than a minute.**
When i try send inputs, it seems to freeze for a few seconds before responding again.

If I let DHCP give them IP, then this does not occur at all.

I thought DHCP conflict was causing it but
I already isolated those ips from my router's DHCP server, it still happens.

How i setup static IPs:

1. disabled cloud-init by creating a file named /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
2. replaced 50-cloud-init.yaml with 01-netcfg.yaml with the following configs:

[image]

3. ran netplan generate, netplan apply and then reboot
4. new IPs were applied.

[image]

Anyone has a clue why this is happening what can i do about it?

Comment: Edit your question and show me how you disabled cloud-init. Do you have any other .yaml files in /etc/netplan? Edit your question and show me `free -h`.

Comment: Are you assigning the SAME IP address to multiple rpi4s? Duplicate IP address break the LAN. That is why DHCP was invented.

Comment: @heynnema i have updated it, and no, there are no other files in /etc/netplan other than 01-netcfg.yaml.

Comment: @waltinator No they have different IPs that screen shot is just one the nodes.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about cloud-init. You have no swap. Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

NTP problem.
systemd-timesyncd fails to sync when using static ip.

Solution:
Replace systemd-timesyncd with ntpd or chrony,
I chose chrony, along with good ntp source.

Answer (score 1):

**cloud-init**

Your `/etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled` should be in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg` and have the following contents...

```
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities,
# write a file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
# with the following content:
#
network: {config: disabled}
```

---

<strike>**swap**</strike>

You have no /swapfile or swap partition. Let's create one...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Add this line to /etc/fstab...

**Note**: Verify that you have no other swap lines in /etc/fstab.

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

**Update #1:**

*About the swap, I can't do since this is going to be a Kubernetes node, which requires swap to removed.*

Comment: Hi @heynnema,

I have tried your cloud-init solution, but still the same.

About the swap, i can't do since this is going to be a Kubernetes node, which requires swap to removed.

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @user3414321 Check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Then go to the RPi web site and check for a newer version.

Comment: @user3414321 Status please...